# How to log visit duration on page?

Tags: php, javascript, visitor-statistic

How to log visit duration on page?

Currently im logging page hits only, by inserting IP, user agent etc. into database.

I know, that I have to use javascript and "onbeforeunload", but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: on load take store the time in a variable on unload store the time in another variable then you do VarTimeUnload - VarTimeLoad using a time function in javascript

Comment: There is NO reliable way to detect when a person leaves your page. At best you can infer how long they stayed by doing `time(visit #2) - time(visit #1)`.

Comment: What about js events body unload, onbeforeunload)? They do not work?

Comment: How do you measure page duration? If I open the page and then I switch tab to other tab, leave the previous tab for 10 hours. How would you handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to test it through jsFiddle (it seems), but you can do something like:

```
function enter() {
    this.crono = new Date().getMilliseconds();
}

function leave() {
    this.crono = new Date().getMilliseconds() - this.crono;
    alert(this.crono);
}

window.onload = enter;
window.onbeforeunload = leave;
```

In place of that `alert(this.crono);` you could launch an ajax call to the server with the `crono` value.

Comment: How to pass this time to PHP? Some ajax call?

Comment: I've read somewhere, that `alert()` function will not work in that event. I will try to put some ajax call and accept your answer if this will work.